# Curley braces in new line not supported anymore?Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, formatting

Vs does not put the Curley braces in new line anymore. Newest version installed. How to fix it?

tried to find some setting in tools/c# but nothing helped.

Comment: Please specify exactly what sequence of keys you're pressing, what you expect and what happens instead. There are a large number of ways to enter braces - all of them might (depending on settings) behave differently.

Comment: buttons pressed, OPTIONS and 8 for {} on Mac layout.

Comment: "cw" and a double tap for "console.WriteLine()" also not working anymore. VS evolving backwards...

Comment: This is all configurable. Check you settings, and check your .editorconfig file.